# Documents automatically checked in

Tags: check-in, content-organizer, records-center

I have a records center with 3 document libraries. Each library has "Require Check Out" set to "Yes" and Versioning to create major versions. I also have Workflows on each library (variants of a content approval-like workflow). The Workflows should kick off when a document is edited/changed. However, when I upload a document it automatically uploads the document in a 'checked-in' state which autofires the Workflows as well. I seem to be having the opposite effect of what should be happening with the above mentioned settings I have enabled. How do I get an upload to remain 'checked-out' until the user checks the document in?

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution is quite simple. Check the document's version in the workflow, and do not execute the approval process if it is 1.0.

Comment: That's a great idea and I will apply that to the workflow. But if it uploads in a checked in state then everyone can see the document immediately. Would i have to also enable content approval required and work modifying that status in the workflow as well?

Comment: You can enable minor version and then configure the library to display only the published versions to users who have only "read" permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the content approval workflow fires when a major version of the file is published. In your case , it seems you have enabled versioning to create major versions only. This will create a new version every time you upload or make changes to documents. Try enable versioning with minor versions in the document library.